# Using GUID (or similar) has performance penalty in Redis?

Tags: redis

Does using a GUID or ulong key impact Redis DB performance?

Similar: [Does name length impact performance in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320739/does-name-length-impact-performance)

Comment: This link has performance benchmarks and accepted answer says not important" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320739/does-name-length-impact-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis use a hash strategy to store all keys, every key is stored using a hash function. All Redis db peformance about keys fall into this function - or something related.

Original key is also stored to figure out future colisions between diferent keys, and yes big keys could be impact at memory handle and all of related fields : memory fragmentation, cache hits/misses, etc ...

Comment: If someone asks to me I answer it as http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373068/501254. But someone made test http://stackoverflow.com/a/6322977/501254 and it seems interesting.

Comment: This answer is misleading, as @ozz mentioned in the comment above, even 300+ char keys don't affect performance.

Answer (score 23):

This question is an old one, but other answers are a bit misleading. Eric's answer is totally unrelated to Redis. Pfreixes's answer is based on personal assumptions and is simply wrong.

In fact, **it's fairly safe to use GUID keys** (performance-wise) as even 300+ character keys don't affect performance significantly on O(1) operations. Check this benchmark: [Does name length impact performance in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320739/does-name-length-impact-performance-in-redis/6322977#6322977).

GUID typically has a length of 32-36 chars, if you're using hex representation. As Evan Carrol noticed in comments, Redis strings are binary safe, so you can use binary value and reduce key size down to 128 bits (16 chars). Keys with such length won't hurt performance at all.

Also, documentation suggests to use hashing functions for really large keys: http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

Comment: UUID have a length of 128 bits, like an md5sum. It has nothing to do with characters.