# Redis - Faster to md5 key before set

Tags: redis, md5

I am wondering if there is a speed increase by md5 the key before calling the redis set method

for example:

```
key = user:100, value = yourvalue, exp = 100
redis->hmset(key, value, exp)
```

or:

```
key = md5(user:100), value = yourvalue, exp = 100
redis->hmset(key, value, exp)
```

Is the second one faster when doing a redis->hgetall(key)?

This would be for using the hash data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would it be faster? You are wasting cpu cycles md5'ing. And the md5 of user:100 will be a longer string so it would be slower if anything.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6322977/583363).